# sas - Apparent symbolic reference not resolved

Tags: sas

The variable department has a value of M&S in the data step

```
set ttt;        
    DepartmentComp=Compress(DepartmentComp);*For use in making directories;       
    CALL SYMPUT('ggg',trim((division)));
    CALL SYMPUT('fff',trim((Department)))
```

the log displays
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FFF resolves to M&S
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference S not resolved.

How can I get rid of the warning as I suspect that it affects the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%superq()` to mask the '&' and prevent resolution of '&S'. Here's an example for you:

```
 60         data test;
 61         comp = "%superq(fff)";
 62         putlog "NOTE: comp=%superq(fff)";
 63         run;

 NOTE: comp=M&S
 NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 1 variables.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using those variables in a subsequent datastep you could use symget to avoid premature attempts at resolution (as follows):

```
data _null_;
   division='%myDiv';
   department='Food&Drink';
   call symputx('ggg',division);
   call symputx('fff',department);
run;

data someds;
   division=symget('ggg');
   department=symget('fff');
   putlog division= department=;
run;
```

Points to note:

- Other than raising an error condition (syscc=4) it's difficult to say if that warning will affect your program (if you create a macro variable of &s it would).  In any case, it's always best to avoid warnings if at all possible.
- You can use symputx instead of symput, which will automatically strip leading / trailing blanks
- The %superq approach proposed by floydn is a good one for direct use in macro logic.

Comment: Thanks but how can I use the macro &fff in a label  statement for example: label division=&fff?